# How to access Carbon object type?

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, laravel-4

Given the following code:

```php
$recordSets = Model::find(1)->get();

foreach ($recordSets as $recordSet) {
  dd($recordSet['created_at']);
}
```

I got this result.

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)[292]
  public 'date' => string '2013-08-21 17:05:19' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

I tried to access the 'date' using

```php
echo $recordSet['created_at']->date;
```

But I got an error:

> Unknown getter 'date'

How to access `$recordSet['created_at']`? It is just for formatting of date/time purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `$recordSet['created_at']`.

Because of a __toString method in Carbon, read `$recordSet['created_at']` will always return the date under string format.

If you want to see which method you can use, see `vendor/nesbot/carbon/Carbon/Carbon.php`

Comment: You are explaining the method behind Carbon, however not the solution to his problem. When calling $recordSet['created_at'] he's receiving an object that contains protected carbon objects. Please reference: http://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2014-how-to-get-timestamp-integer-instead-of-carbon-object

Comment: This is wrong and should not be accepted. $recordSet['created_at'] returns Carbon Object not a string. Sherif's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 31):

you should use the public function toDateTimeString()

```
echo $recordSet['created_at']->toDateTimeString();
```

Comment: Error: Call to a member function toDateTimeString() on a non-object

Comment: try $recordSet->toDateTimeString(); then get the stringified data in $recordSet['created_at']

Answer (score 4):

```
  public function getDates() {
        return array();
  }
```

Place this code in your model. This will disable date mutations.